# Whose solubility increases with increase in temperature?

Tags: aqueous-solution, solubility, ionic-compounds, temperature

> Solubility of which among the following substances in **water** increases slightly with rise in temperature?
>
> (a)$\ce{KBr}$
>
> (b)$\ce{KCl}$
>
> (c)$\ce{KNO3}$
>
> (d)$\ce{NaNO3}$

Answer is (b).

I don't know why.
According to me if temperature is increased then Bonds between any of these four must be broken due to supplied energy & solubility must decrease. And what about the other three. Do they too also show the same trend.

Answer (score 6):

All four substances have higher solubility at higher temperatures in the range from 0 to 100 degrees Celsius.

$\ce{KBr}$ and $\ce{KCl}$ both roughly double their solubility from 0 to 100 degrees Celsius.

To me the question does not make sense.

Comment: In case of KCl there is stronger ionic lattice and at lower temperature entire lattice will not break during dissolution at lower temperature and at higher temperature this lattice  absorb energy and get dissociated. So there is increase in solubility with increase in temperature. In others lattice is weaker due to larger size of anion.